# Pseudo element ::after has no height

Tags: css, sass

I've got a strange one. I use this same bit of code all over my site, and it works everywhere. For some reason, it simply wont work here.

Basically what I am doing is creating a translucent background image by using pseudo elements `:before` and `:after`to fill the entire container with a background color (`:before`) and a semi-transparent image (`:after`). The `:before` element works just fine, it fills the height and width of the `.dashboard-page` as expected. The `:after` element has 100% width, but a height of 0, so the image is not showing up. Help would be much appreciated.

```
.dashboard-page {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    @include clearfix;

    &:before,
    &:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        @include transition($transition-main);
    }

    &:before {
        z-index: -2;                    
        background-color: $blue-light;
    }

    &:after {
        opacity: 0.02;
        z-index: -1;    
        background-image: url('../life/assets/img/pattern.png');                
    }
}
```

Comment: try changing `content: ''` to `content: ' '` with a space

Comment: Do you have a demo of this?

Comment: It seems your clearfix may be overriding your other css

Comment: Without more code, this is not reproducible.  http://jsfiddle.net/yeykmwxx/2/.  Have to wonder why you're using pseudo elements for this rather than multiple backgrounds:  http://css-tricks.com/tinted-images-multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: Cimmanon - I'm using pseudo elements instead of multiple backgrounds because the background image itself needs to be semi-transparent, while the color needs to be fully opaque. I also use the same pattern with multiple different colors on the site, so instead of having to have multiple background images getting called, I opted to use a pseudo element instead so I could adjust the opacity of my background image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding `display: block;` to `:after`.

By default pseudo elements are inline boxes

Comment: Display block fixed it, even though I haven't needed to use this anywhere else on the site. Weirdest thing. Thanks for your help, @derek_duncan.

Comment: Glad we could get it fixed @idealbrandon